# how to dynamically get a single value from a datatable in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable, row, calculated-columns

I am new at C#, I have a DataTable named dt; Now I want to get the values from it's each row and a specific column named "Number" from which I can calculate a third column to add. But cant' do it. Any ideas? Please help me.

```
foreach (DataRow dRow in dt.Rows)
    {
        int number = dt.Rows[0].Field<int>(1);

        dRow[Ratio] = Convert.ToString(((number * 100) / grandTotal)) + " %";

    }
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Doesn't your code throw you an `NotEvenTriedException`?

Comment: Here is what I am trying out. I want to add a third calculated column depending on the values of a specific column. Please help me out. Running out of dead line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop and the [`Field` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx), presuming that `Number` is an `int`:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    int number = row.Field<int>("Number");
    // do your calculation
    row.SetField("ThirdColumn", someValue);
}
```

Comment: I am adding a third calculated column depending on the values of the specific column, but can't get the Number column value while using foreach loop. Please help me out. Running out of dead line

Comment: @Slasher_bd: your code makes no sense. `int number = dt.Rows[0].Field<int>(1);` This is always the first row but you're laready looping the rows. So the corerct way would be: `int number = dRow.Field<int>(1);`

Comment: Thanks @Tim. You saved my life. your last comment did the job. Thanks again